# Python Pie chart from CSV data

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I have a .csv file that contains 3 columns that I must read into Python and convert to a pie plot.

I've managed to produce a pie chart plot if I create lists manually of the data, but I'm stuck on reading the data from my .csv into python.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

outfile = open("vote_results.csv","r")

file=csv.reader(outfile)
#skip the headers
next(file, None)

Party = []
Seats = []
Votes = []

for row in file:
    Party = row[0]
    Seats = row[1]
    Votes = row[2]

plt.pie(Votes, labels=Party)
plt.show()
```

I keep getting:

```
TypeError: "Object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len()"
```

which I thought was due to having headers and so tried

```
next(file, None)
```

to remove them but still get the error.

The CSV file looks like

```
Party      Seats       Votes

Party1      50           1000

Party2      41           680

Party3      32           481
```

[screenshot of console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjam7.png)

[screenshot of .csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztH98.png)

Comment: Can you provide the full output?

Comment: And can you provide an example of what your csv file looks like

Comment: The output is a blank "plot" with x and y axis from 0-1 in 0.2 increments.

I'm not sure how to format my comment but the csv is a table with 3 columns each with a header 


Party Seats Votes
Party1 1000 74744
Party2 447  8830
Party3 3      521
etc

Comment: @abybaddi009 #
I have added screenshots of the console output

Thanks

Comment: @DavidG 

I have added a screenshot of the csv file

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the way you are trying to store the data. You have initialised an empty list using `Party = []`, but you then overwrite the variable named `Party` to be the result of `row[0]`. Therefore, when you come to try and plot a pie chart, you only have one number in the list you are trying to plot.

The solution is to *append* the items into your list using `my_list.append(value)`. Also, I'm not sure if it is a typo, but you need brackets after `plt.show()`.

Note that according to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), variable names should start with a lowercase letter.

You can also add `plt.axis('equal')` to make the pie chart circular as suggested by @Dan in the comments.

Therefore, your example would become:

```
outfile = open("vote_results.csv","r")

file=csv.reader(outfile)
next(file, None)

party = []
seats = []
votes = []

for row in file:
    party.append(row[0])
    seats.append(row[1])
    votes.append(row[2])

plt.pie(votes, labels=party)
plt.axis('equal') # make the pie chart circular
plt.show()
```

Which using the sample data gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! solved my problem there.
(yeah, the missing brackets was a typo from copying my code over)
Happy new year!